# how to rectify the date set to null error in IOS devices using ionic 1 framework with angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing hybrid apps using ionic framework. I have one problem in date setting. I had fetched some date from the database, and set to the particular field. It is working fine in the android devices but not working in Ios devices. It showing always null in that field. Kindly guide me.

Comment: show us some code....which input type your using??